# Getting invalid grant when refreshing microsoft access oktne

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, refresh-token

I have create a web app that the user can connect his account with his outlook account, which will allow him to control his calendar using my web application.

I get the user consent and get access token and refresh token, it all works fine.
When I refresh the token lets say after 30 minutes I get the new access token.

But after a while, a day I think I start getting this error `invalid_grant` when I refresh the token, And I have to login again to outlook to get a valid access token.

Does anyone have any idea why does this happen? This only happens the next day
by the way I have `offline_access` in my scope and API permission

Here is the request I am sending

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token' \
--header 'Origin: http://localhost:4200' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer ${Access_Token}' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Cookie: fpc=AhDVWlE6NztJuqGq2Z_Q19xuuUk8AQAAAL3-ytsOAAAA; stsservicecookie=estsfd; x-ms-gateway-slice=estsfd' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=f4c91f15-2a7c-4b57-836d-5b11dbd37981' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=user.read calendars.readwrite offline_access openid profile' \
--data-urlencode 'refresh_token=${Refresh_Token}' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=refresh_token'
```

And here is the error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I registered one Azure AD application and added same **API permissions** as below:

[image]

I generated **tokens** using authorization code with PKCE flow via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:authorization_code
client_id:<appID>
scope: user.read calendars.readwrite offline_access openid profile
code:code
redirect_uri: http://localhost:4200
code_verifier: S256
```

**Response:**

[image]

I am able to fetch **access token** using this refresh token successfully **until 24 hrs** like below:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id:<appID>
scope:user.read calendars.readwrite offline_access openid profile
refresh_token:<paste_refresh_token_from_above>
grant_type:refresh_token
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I tried to refresh the token *after 24 hrs*, I got **same error** like below:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id:<appID>
scope:user.read calendars.readwrite offline_access openid profile
refresh_token:<paste_refresh_token_from_above>
grant_type:refresh_token
```

**Response:**

[image]

The error usually occurs if you register your **redirect URI** as `SPA` as below:

[image]

As mentioned in this [**MS Documentation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/EN-US/azure/active-directory/develop/refresh-tokens#refresh-token-lifetime),

> The default lifetime for the refresh tokens is 24 hours for [single page apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/EN-US/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-third-party-cookies-spas). Refresh tokens sent to a redirect URI registered as `spa` expire after 24 hours.
>
> So, you need to rerun the authorization code flow using an interactive authentication to get a new refresh token every 24 hours.

Alternatively, you can register new Azure AD application by setting platform of **redirect URI** to `Web` and generate tokens with normal *authorization code* flow where refresh token stays for **90 days**.